# Is there a way in Scala to remove the mutable variable(s) or it is fine to keep the mutable variables in the below case?

Tags: scala, immutability, mutability

I understand that Scala embraces immutability fully.

Now I am thinking a scenario that I have to hold some state (via variables) in a class or such. I will need to update these variables later; then I can revisit the class later to access the updated variables.

I will try to make it simple with one very straightforward example:

```
class A {
  var x: Int
  def compute: Int = {calling some other processes or such using x as input}
}
```

......

```
def invoker() {
  val a: A = new A
  a.x = 1
  ......
  val res1 = a.compute
  a.x = 5
  ......
  val res2 = a.compute
  ......
}
```

So you see, I need to keep changing x and get the results. If you argue that I can simply keep x as an argument for compute such as

```
def compute(x: Int) 
......
```

That's a good idea but I cannot do it in my case as I need to separate setting value for x and computing the result completely. In other words, setting x value should not trigger "computing" to occur, rather, I need to be able to set x value anytime in the program and be able to reuse the value for computation any other time in the program when I need it.

I am using a variable (var x: Int) in this case. Is this legitimate or there is still some immutable way to handle it?

Comment: When do you need to set value `x`? Could you make the piece of code that calls `compute` read the value `x` from the place that would set it normally? Note that there *are* cases where you cannot possibly write a fully immutable program, notably when I/O is involved.

Comment: I need to be able to set value x anytime I want. I would keep variable x with compute method in the same class so I can pass the whole class around for other purposes. So yeah, I think you are right, in some cases, a fully immutable program is not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you store state you will need to use mutability.

In your case, you want to store **x** and compute separately. Inherently, this means state is required since the results of **compute** depends on the state of **x**

If you really want the class with **compute** to be immutable, then some other mutable class will need to contain **x** and it will need to be passed to the compute method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea, I think the same way but just want to confirm :)

Answer (score 0):

> rather, I need to be able to set x value anytime in the program and be able to reuse the value for computation any other time in the program when I need it.

Then, by definition you want your class to be stateful. You could restructure your problem so that particular class doesn't require state, but whether that's useful and/or worth the hassle is something you'll have to figure out.

Comment: Right, I don't intent to over-engineer code but just want to achieve the best we can with minimum code efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is used in a `ListBuffer` for example (with `size` as your `compute` function).

So yes, there might be cases where you can use this pattern for good reasons. Example:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)

val lb = new ListBuffer[Int]
l.foreach(n => lb += n * n)
val result = lb.toList

println(result)
```

On the other hand a buffer is normally only used to create an immutable instance as soon as possible. If you look at this code, there are two items which might indicate that it can be changed: The mutable buffer and `foreach` (because `foreach` is only called for its side-effects)

So another option is

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)

val result = l.map(n => n * n)

println(result)
```

which does the same in fewer lines. I prefer this style, because your are just looking at immutable instances and "functional" functions.

In your abstract example, you could try to separate the mutable state and the function:

```
class X(var i: Int)

class A {
  def compute(x: X): Int = { ... }
}
```

possibly even

```
class X(val i: Int)
```

This way `compute` becomes functional: It's return value only depends from the parameter.

My personal favorite regarding an "unexpected" immutable class is `scala.collection.immutable.Queue`. With an "imperative" background, you just not expect a queue to be immutable.

So if you look at your pattern, it's likely that you can change it to being immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an immutable A class (here its a case class) and let an object handle the mutability. For each state change we create a new A object and change the reference in the object. This is handle concurrency bit better if you set x from a different thread, you just have to make the variable a volatile or an AtomicReference.

```
object A {
    private[this] var a = A(0)
    def setX(x: Int) { if (x != a.x) a = new A(x) }
    def getA: A = a
}

case class A(x: Int) {
    def compute: Int = { /*do your stuff*/ }
}
```

Comment: setX needs to be `synchronized` ? Also what's the purpose of privatizing to `this` instead of just `private` ?

Answer (score 0):

After a few more months on functional programming, here is my rethinking.

Every time a variable is modified/changed/updated/mutated, the imperative way of handling this is to record such change right with that variable. The functional way of thinking is to make the activity (that cause the change) bring the new state to you. In other words, it's like cause effect stuff. Functional way thinking focuses on the transition activity between cause and effect.

Given all that, in any given point of time in the program execution, our achievement is the intermediate result. We need somewhere to hold the result no matter how we do it. Such intermediate result is the state and yes, we need some variable to hold it. That's what I want to share with just abstract thinking.